# How to use a variable in regexp expression (TCL/Expect)

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I'm trying to figure out how to use a string in a regexp match. I have been searching on google for an hour, figured i would just ask the experts.

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set MYSTR "value"

if [ regexp -nocase "$MYSTR" $outcome matchresult ] then {
...
}
```

This is not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set MYSTR "value"

if [ regexp -nocase {something here:\s+$MYSTR} $outcome matchresult ] then {
...
}
```

I'm sure it's a simple syntax problem.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right. You have 2 options: enclose the pattern with `"` , but then you have to protect `\` from being parsed by Tcl instead of the regxp. Or you can use `regexp -nocase [subst -nocommands -nobackslashes {something here:\s+$MYSTR}]`.

PS: put always `{}` [around the](http://tclhelp.net/unb/194) [expression](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225):

```
if {[regexp -nocase [subst -nocommands -nobackslashes {something here:\s+$MYSTR}]} then {
...
}
```