# passing variables inside a regexp in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a variable in regexp expression (TCL/Expect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768739/how-to-use-a-variable-in-regexp-expression-tcl-expect)

I want help in passing varibles to a regexp.

Suppose my code is

```
set line "MPID:22 condition:AIS"
set id 22
if {[regexp {MPID:$id} $line]} {
puts "inside if"
}
```

This regexp doesn't work. If I change regexp to

```
{[regexp {MPID:22} $line]}
```

it works.

Can someone provide a solution for this.

Comment: Read chapters 5 through 7 of the [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) to understand why your `$id` variable reference is not expanded. Reading the whole tutorial is advised.

Comment: Check below link, it is nicely answered there:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768739/how-to-use-a-variable-in-regexp-expression-tcl-expect

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of `{MPID:$id}` you want to use `"MPID:$id"`:

```
if {[regexp "MPID:$id" $line]} {
    puts "inside if"
}
```

The `{...}` are used by tcl to group parts of an expression together but prevent variable expansion.
If you want variable expansion you should use `"..."`

Comment: Note: When you move from {} to "", make sure that additional escape chars are added. For e.g., if you had {\s*}, change it to "\\s*"

Comment: I have no idea as to why a double escape char is necessary, but the information is invaluable.

Comment: @vineeshvs I would literally hug you right now. This double escape was literally the holy grail to create dynamic patterns. Thanks !